# render partial does not display no errors in console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial on my page There are no errors in the console or in my terminal log the scenario is ... that the user selects a link on the page and the middle area should render. I am running this thru jquery and letting the submit go to my controller 'session' and the method 'showsurvey' it gets the information necessary and then renders to a showsurvey.js.erb to replace the html with the showsurvey partial

here is the code involved ....shownewuser.html.erb

```
        <%= include_gon %>


<div id="content" class="clearfix">
```

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/user_profile' %>
      <div class="inner">

        <div class="top_area">          
          </div> <!-- top_area -->               
          <p>Welcome <%=@user.email%> Drag the topics into the order of importance to you.</p>
           <div id="middle_area" > 
            <%= render :partial => 'middle_newuser' %>
      <div id="find">
         <p>Where voters and politicians can discuss and learn  about the issues for free with no advertising dollars getting in the way <br />
         Subscribe to RSS feeds to stay in touch with their latest votes. </p>
      </div>

</div>   <!-- inner_area -->
```

The orginal partial to replace _middle_newuser.html.erb

```
              <div id = "draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Issues</h3>
         <table>
         <tr><td>
        <ul id ="column1" >
        <% (0..5).each do |i| %>
         <% @sm_pic= @cat[i][:small_pic] 
            @CatName = @cat[i][:name] 
            @id = @cat[i][:id]%>
               <li id="draggable">
            <%= link_to image_tag(@sm_pic, :border => 0), showsurvey_path({:data => @id}), :remote => true, :data => @id , :id => 'showSurvey'  %>
          </li> 
         <% end %>  
        </ul>
          </td>
                   <td>
           <ul id ="column1"  >
           <% (6..11).each do |i| %>
           <% @sm_pic= @cat[i][:small_pic] 
            @CatName = @cat[i][:name] 
            @id = @cat[i][:id]%>
                <li id="draggable">
            <%= link_to image_tag(@sm_pic, :border => 0), showsurvey_path, :data => @id %>
                         </li>
              <% end %>
        </ul>
         </td>
           <td>
         <ul id ="column1"  >  
         <% (12..17).each do |i| %>
         <% @sm_pic= @cat[i][:small_pic] 
            @CatName = @cat[i][:name] 
            @id = @cat[i][:id]%>
               <li id="draggable">
            <%= link_to image_tag(@sm_pic, :border => 0), showsurvey_path, :data => @id %>
              </li>

         <% end %>
          </ul>
             </td></tr>
         </table>
         </div id>  <!-- draggable -->
           </div>  <!-- middle_area -->
```

and the partial that should replace this ...._middle_survey.html.erb

```
             <div>
         <table><tr>
           <div id="middle_area-left" >
           <p>Welcome this will be the survey page for user after clicking on a priority icon.</p>
           </div>
           <div id="middle_area-center" >
           <%= render :partial => 'form' %>
           </div>
           <div id="middle_area-right" >
           <p>Welcome this will be the survey page for user after clicking on a priority icon.</p>
           </div>
           </tr>
           </table>
           </div>
```

The controller method is  showSurvey

```
  def showsurvey
  @title = "Survey for"
   @category = Category.find(params[:data])
       @questions = @category.questions.find_all_by_category_id(params[:data])
       @current_question_rec =  @questions.first
       @current_question = @current_question_rec.question
       @current_question_id = @current_question_rec.question_id
       @answer = @category.questions.find(@current_question_id).answers.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to @category }
         format.js { render }
 end
```

`end`

last the showSurvey.js.erb

```
$(#middle_area').replace_html( "<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "middle_survey" %> ");
```

One more thing here's the output from my terminal

```
Processing by SessionsController#showsurvey as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3", "data"=>"3"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
  Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."category_id" = 3 AND "questions"."category_id" = '3'
  Question Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."category_id" = 3 AND "questions"."question_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["question_id", 1]]
  Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 1 AND "answers"."user_id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/_form.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered sessions/_middle_survey.html.erb (5.8ms)
  Rendered sessions/showsurvey.html.erb (7.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 13.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#middle_area').replace_html( "<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "middle_survey" %> ");
```

looks like a typo, you forgot forward quotes.

$(**'**#middle_area')

Also, I'm not so good at CSS, but I can't see div `#middle_area` itself, are you sure that jquery can parse `#middle_area-right` and so on?

Comment: ah I see what your saying but they are actual valid css elements I would assume that it would tree down this but I'm not sure my self. I did change the js thanks and found some other typos as well but still no go.

Comment: you can make quick test and throw alert if element found

Comment: Also, remove brackets with format.js {render}, cause here you are just passing nil. I checked your link, I'm pretty sure, that the reason why rails even don't parse js file, is because yours syntax breaks the rules of link_to. Check you link in brouser, doesn't it pass :remote=> true as params? Is there nofollow tag?

Comment: nope, checked, link has data-remote tag, but be aware while debugging, that your js partial not even rendered, as this part of consolelog shows

Comment: Its now using the js. instead but still now display  Started GET     Answer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 8 AND "answers"."user_id" = 4 LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/_form.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered sessions/_middle_survey.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered sessions/showsurvey.js.erb (7.7ms)

Comment: I walked thru the event and this is the preview of the event it actually is built so it seems to be when the render is complete it does not replace the actually section of the page I am stumped could it be something that jquery sets that I not aware of ?????

Comment: As I sad, start from the beginning and check if Jquery sees #middle_area element on page, by throwing an alert if is

Comment: how and where would I check jquery run on demand so I'm not sure where I would place the alert

Comment: in showSurvey.js.erb: `if ($('#middle_area').length>0) {alert("JQ sees it!")`

Comment: going to try it now.... its not seeing it no alert displayed going to check my css now

Comment: ok, now remove from any of divs that left-right part and try again

Comment: Joe think this has to do with the form partial thats were the render to middle area ends. So I believe this is a form_tag issue will test this and let you know and again thanks for the help

Comment: Walking thru jquery results in a break when checking the content-type going to check out why now but if you can enlight me that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue all the wonderful jquery returns like "replace_html" etc does not work because when you render the js from the controller it is thinks its plain old js and therefore it returns to the prototype object (buried deep in jquery ) I actually found this by reading another stackoverflow question answered "replacing Prototype with jquery-rails - replace_html causes errors"

Bottom line is you really need to debug online and walk thru jquery to see where the error is created:

In my case it was it existed in a function of 
jquery called ajaxConvert( s, response )

...... once I entered the object in the console

```
    conv( response ) it displayed the following .....
```

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace_html' on render rails 
By searching for that I found the stackoverflow question answer. 
Once again baptised by fire!